# After upgrading, getting "Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test" and "test(s) <[]> cannot be found"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins, testng

I upgraded Selenium to support GeckoDriver, and then Jenkins with it. I'm pretty new to this behind-the-scenes-upgrading stuff. Since we're running Selenium 3, we no longer use the Selenium Grid plugin. I haven't been able to get any tests to run since then.

We run Windows 7 machines for the Jenkins master and slaves. If it makes any difference, we use Java. We also have a framework sitting atop Selenium.

In particular is this error that really bugs me:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project example-project: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The test(s) <[]> cannot be found.
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.extractTestNames(TestNG.java:436)
```

I tried a little to alter the forking config but to no avail.

I've also played with the TestNG scope in the POM, but turning it to `test` causes TestNG classes to "not exist".

## Full Results

Here are the full results I've been getting (run with Maven -e flag; I have the results with -X if needed):

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace
Updating https://subversion.example.com/svn/example-test-center/trunk/FunctionalAutomation/ExampleProject at revision '2017-02-10T15:33:28.095 -0500'
A         target\log4j2.xml
At revision 3234

No changes for https://subversion.example.com/svn/example-test-center/trunk/FunctionalAutomation/ExampleProject since the previous build
Parsing POMs
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
Established TCP socket on 60174
[workspace] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java" -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;C:\Maven3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Maven3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main C:\Maven3.3.9\apache-maven-3.3.9 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.4.1.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar" 60174
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\pom.xml clean test -e -DsuiteFile=src/main/test/suites/ca/alpha/desktop/QA_Brochures_Test.xml -Drunvehicle=All Models -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\browser-drivers\geckodriver-win64.exe
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.automation:example-project:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.example.automation:automation-util:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/resources/lib/automation-util-1.18.1.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 105, column 16
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.client.servicesapi:servicesapi:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/src/resources/lib/ServicesClientLibrary-1.2.112.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 112, column 16
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ExampleProject 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ example-project ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:add-source (add-source) @ example-project ---
[INFO] Source directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\src\main\objects added.
[INFO] Source directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\src\main\test\classes added.
[INFO] Source directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\src\main\test\suites added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:3.0.0:add-resource (add-resource) @ example-project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ example-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\src\main\resources
[INFO] Copying 19 resources to resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ example-project ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 212 source files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\target\classes
[INFO] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/QA_Brochures_Test/workspace/src/main/objects/com/alpha/global/components/MyPlan.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[INFO] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/QA_Brochures_Test/workspace/src/main/objects/com/alpha/global/components/MyPlan.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/QA_Brochures_Test/workspace/src/main/test/classes/com/alpha/global/TC_GUX_BNP.java: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\src\main\test\classes\com\alpha\global\TC_GUX_BNP.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[INFO] /C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins/jobs/QA_Brochures_Test/workspace/src/main/test/classes/com/alpha/global/TC_GUX_BNP.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ example-project ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ example-project ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) @ example-project ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\test-output

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run? 
For example, C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\test-output\TEST-TestSuite.xml is 1 mo 7 days old

    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:228)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:623)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoFailed(Maven3Builder.java:656)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy.onEvent(Maven3Builder.java:300)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.onEvent(EventSpyDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyExecutionListener.mojoFailed(EventSpyExecutionListener.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:90)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:133)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:68)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.752 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-10T15:33:50-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/265M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project example-project: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] The test(s) <[]> cannot be found.
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.extractTestNames(TestNG.java:436)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1088)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project example-project: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
org.testng.TestNGException: 

The test(s) <[]> cannot be found.
    at org.testng.TestNG.extractTestNames(TestNG.java:436)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1088)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:133)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:68)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
org.testng.TestNGException: 

The test(s) <[]> cannot be found.
    at org.testng.TestNG.extractTestNames(TestNG.java:436)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1088)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error in the forked process
org.testng.TestNGException: 

The test(s) <[]> cannot be found.
    at org.testng.TestNG.extractTestNames(TestNG.java:436)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:310)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1088)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:460)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:229)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:201)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1026)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 32 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\QA_Brochures_Test\workspace\pom.xml to com.example.automation/example-project/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/example-project-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: FAILURE
```

## POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.automation</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-project</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExampleProject</name>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/main/objects</source>
                                <source>src/main/test/classes</source>
                                <source>src/main/test/suites</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>add-resource</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-resource</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/resources</directory>
                                    <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <reuseForks>false</reuseForks> -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/${suiteFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/test-output</reportsDirectory>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>testnames</name>
                            <value>${testname}</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>runvehicle</name>
                            <value>${runVehicle}</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example.automation</groupId>
            <artifactId>automation-util</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/resources/lib/automation-util-1.18.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.client.servicesapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>servicesapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.112</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/src/resources/lib/ServicesClientLibrary-1.2.112.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.10</version>
            <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- When updating Selenium here, ensure automation-util's POM is updated also! -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.qualitycheck/quality-check -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.qualitycheck</groupId>
            <artifactId>quality-check</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

## Suite XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="FOC Brochures">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.example.util.result.CustomReportListener" />
    </listeners>

    <parameter name="browser" value="gecko" />
    <parameter name="mailingList" value="AUTO, FOC" />
    <parameter name="remote" value="true" />
    <parameter name="model" value="${runVehicle}" />

    <test name="QA-Alpha-English">
        <parameter name="baseUrl" value="http://wwwmgqa.alpha.ca/brochures/" />
        <classes>
            <class name="ca.alpha.desktop.TC_FOC_Brochures">
                <methods>
            <!-- 
                    <include name="init" />
             -->
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="QA-Alpha-French">
        <parameter name="baseUrl" value="http://fr-wwwmgqa.alpha.ca/brochures/" />
        <classes>
            <class name="ca.alpha.desktop.TC_FOC_Brochures">
                <methods>
            <!-- 
                    <include name="init" />
             -->
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Any ideas on how to remedy this? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**
After removing `testnames` from Surefire completely and running again, I'm now getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project example-project: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Cannot instantiate class com.example.util.result.CustomReportListener
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.newInstance(ClassHelper.java:53)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeConfiguration(TestNG.java:981)
[ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1089)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:281)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:121)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[ERROR] at org.testng.internal.ClassHelper.newInstance(ClassHelper.java:51)
[ERROR] ... 8 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR] at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$200(Win32ShellFolder2.java:72)
[ERROR] at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:242)
[ERROR] at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Win32ShellFolder2.java:237)
[ERROR] at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[ERROR] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[ERROR] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[ERROR] at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Win32ShellFolderManager2.java:547)
[ERROR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Where the `CustomReportListener` class is inside the automation-util JAR, which is stored in `src/resources/lib` typically, though I've also tested it in a class source folder (`src/main/test/classes`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your surefire plugin configuration indicates that you would be choosing both the suite file and also the set of tests ( `<test>` tags) at run time via JVM arguments.

`<property>
    <name>testnames</name>
    <value>${testname}</value>
</property>`

Please ensure that you pass a valid value to the set of `<test>` tags via the JVM argument `-Dtestnames`.

Comment: This wasn't helpful for me, but thank you. `testnames` is an optional parameter for us.

Comment: @skia.heliou Your surefire plugin configuration suggests that its not an optional parameter but its something that is mandatory. If it were to be optional then you would have had an entry in the <properties></properties> section of your pom file.

Comment: These are parameters we only pass via Jenkins for TestNG: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#properties

Comment: @skia.heliou - I understand that. But here TestNG is complaining that you passed an empty value for the property "testnames". Can you try passing in a value for it and see if that fixes the problem ? That will basically clear out all the doubts.

Comment: I see what you mean. I ran it with a value and I also ran it with `testnames` removed from the POM. Both ways produce the same result as above.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the same results after all. Please see update at end.

Comment: @skia.heliou - Please see if this SO thread helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614605/npe-in-win32shellfolder2-access-when-creating-new-jfilechooser-as-local-system-a

Comment: This thread feels like a different issue. All I know for sure is that my custom listener can't be found, though it doesn't seem to have a problem with any of the other classes in the JAR. I should probably create a new question for this...

Comment: Now see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42210732/maven-surefire-cant-instantiate-my-ireporter-class-on-jenkins

Comment: I now confirm that it was the `$testnames` parameter for certain. What a nightmare. @Krishnan, thanks for the help ☺

Answer (score 0):

Replace maven compiler plugin in pom.xml with following plugin. Hope so it will work.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
```

Comment: This isn't really a replacement so much as a version upgrade from 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. This occurs when you import the project and try to build it.
 Make sure you have these steps setup properly:

1. Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs =pointing to jdk 1.8
2. Right click on the project and select Properties and then click on 'Project Facets' and make sure the right selections are made like Dynamic Web Module and version number, Java and its version. On the right pane ,select the Runtimes tab and make sure to check the correct Tomcat version that you are trying to run the project on.