# Exception while Running Javafx app from jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, javafx-8

I am running a javafx based application from jenkins. My Jenkins version is 2.73.1 and java application is compiled with java 8 and i am running the jar with java8 as well.  I am having this exception and this actually starts here without giving any detail.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried a lot of solutions, changing jenkins versions, logon to jenkins as administrator but nothing work.

It is not the duplicate of '[NPE in Win32ShellFolder2.access when creating new JFileChooser as Local System Account in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614605/npe-in-win32shellfolder2-access-when-creating-new-jfilechooser-as-local-system-a)'  as it is working perfectly fine in my pc from command prompt.

Any hint or help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPE in Win32ShellFolder2.access when creating new JFileChooser as Local System Account in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23614605/npe-in-win32shellfolder2-access-when-creating-new-jfilechooser-as-local-system-a)

Comment: I have actually tried the solutions provided here. Moreover the same javafx application gets successfully executed when run from command prompt in my pc.

Comment: Is Jenkins running with JDK 1.7+? Seems to be a problem that got fixed with the Java 1.7 release!

Comment: my class path variable for java (JAVA_HOME) is pointing toward 1.7 whereas i am running this javafx app with 1.8 because this app builts with jdk 1.8 and jenkins is also running with jdk 1.8